# ReactJS container does not take up entire line

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a reactJS application where I display a heading at the top of the view and then some text under the heading.  I am using this code to generate the view:

```
render() {
    return (
    <div>   
    <div className="container">
        <div className="enrollment_heading_background">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 text-center">
                    <label>Online Enrollment</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="container">
        <div className="enrollment_background">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 text-center text_15">
                    <label>Participant Agreement for OnLine Enrollment</label>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

And I have the following in my style sheet:

```
.enrollment_heading_background {
   background-color: #b3ccff;
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
 }
.enrollment_background {    
   background-color: #ffe6b3;
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

This is what is showing in the view:

[image]

If you notice, there is whitespace on the left and on the right.  I have been unsuccessful in getting the blue background of the heading to occupy the entire view and I have been unsuccessful in getting the beige background to occupy the entire view.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: right now I am rendering to a browser (chrome). I will look at the developer tools to see if I can figure out who owns those areas.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<div className="enrollment_heading_background">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 text-center">
                <label>Online Enrollment</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div className="enrollment_background">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 text-center text_15">
                <label>Participant Agreement for OnLine Enrollment</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The padding from your container is causing the white space. You can still keep the container padding but bring the background divs out so they wrap both containers and keep their 100% width.

Comment: Perfect!  I was always under the impression that the container needed to be the outermost <div>.  @Chris pointed me in the direction of looking into the styles and I found that the default .container had 15px left and right. I created a .container_no_border without the left right and that worked as well but I like your solution better.  Thanks to all.